# AngularJS- logout from website not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

I'm developing a website using angularJS and PHP. Users can login if credentials are valid and if valid, PHP sets a session and returns a token which I store in localStorage.

I created  a service which checks for authenticity of the token. I have a logout controller as well. But my logout feature is not working properly. I remove local storage token and destroy the session and I get navigated to index page but I can still view other pages my changing the URL.

This is my **login controller**

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module('myApp.login', [])

  .controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.post = {};
    $scope.post.login = [];
    $scope.vm = {};
    $scope.index = '';

    var baseUrl = 'api/';

    // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred            
    vm.login = function(isValid) {
      // check to make sure the form is completely valid
      if (isValid) {
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: baseUrl + 'login',
            data: $.param($scope.vm),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          })
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.success) {
              if (localStorage['token']) {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
              }
              localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(data.login_token));

              $location.path('/home');
            } else {

              if (localStorage['token']) {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
              }

              vm.errorMessage = data.msg;
            }
          }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          if (localStorage['token']) {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
          }
          vm.errorMessage = data.msg;
        });
      }
    };


  });

})();
```

Once login is successful,  set a token. You can see that above And then I redirect user to **Home Controller** which looks like this:

```
-(function() {

    angular
      .module('myApp.home', [])

    .factory('myHomeService', function($http) {
      var baseUrl = 'api/';
      return {
        getUserSessInfo: function() {
          return $http.get(baseUrl + 'get_user_session');
        }
      };
    })

    .controller('HomeController', function($scope, $routeParams, myHomeService, AuthService) {
        var vm = this;
        var token;
        if (localStorage['token']) {
          token = JSON.parse(localStorage['token']);
        } else {
          token = "";
        }

        if (token) {
          AuthService.checkToken(token);

          //To get user session value
          myHomeService.getUserSessInfo().success(function(data) {
            vm.id = data.id;
            //vm.userName   = data.username;
          });

          $scope.logout = function() {
            var data = {
              token: token
            }
            AuthService.logOut(token);
          }

        });
    })();
```

In home controller, I check for the token and call the service `AuthService` which does user authentication.

Here is **AuthService**. It has two functions. One to check token and other to do logout.

```
(function() {

angular
.module('myApp.AuthenticationService', [])

.factory('AuthService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
    var vm = this;
    var baseUrl = 'api/';
    vm.checkToken = function(token)
    {        
        var data = {token: token};

        $http.post(baseUrl + 'validateUserToken', data).success(function(response)
        {
            if (response.msg === "unauthorized")
            {
                //console.log("Logged out");
                $location.path('/login');
            } 
            else 
            {
                //console.log("Logged In");
                return response.msg;
            }
        }).error(function(error)
        {
            $location.path('/login');
        })

    }

    vm.logOut = function(token)
    {        
        var data = {token: token};

        $http.post(baseUrl + 'destroyUserToken', data).success(function(response)
        {
            if (response.msg === "Logged out")
            {
                 localStorage.clear();
                //console.log("Logged out");
                $location.path('/login');
            } 
        }).error(function(error)
        {
                localStorage.clear();
            $location.path('/login');
        })

    }
   return vm;
}]);

})();
```

And when user click a logout link, **logout controller** is called. Here it is:

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module('myApp.logout', [])

  .controller('LogoutController', function($scope, $routeParams, AuthService) {
    var vm = this;

    //If user is not logged in
    var token;
    if (localStorage['entrp_token']) {
      token = JSON.parse(localStorage['entrp_token']);
    } else {
      token = "something stupid";
    }
    AuthService.logOut(token);

  });
})();
```

But even after doing all this, user can navigate to older pages by changing the url. How can i prevent this?

Comment: when user navigates to older pages by changing the url does your server responds with new data to use ?

Comment: Yes..the functions which doesnot use session parameters returns results and the ones using session parameters returns error. @Arif

Comment: so you want to redirect user back to login page if they are not logged in and trying to view older pages, right ?

Comment: Yes....exactly. i don't  want them accessing pages after logout. I have many controllers like Home controller and thi s needs to be checked there as well. @Arif

Comment: You can use `resolve` on your  `routes`. 
if you can provide a fiddle i can try to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resolve` on your routes to find out if user is logged in or no before rendering the template.

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/102s4t46/) to have an idea how to do it

```
var onlyLoggedIn = function ($location,$q,Auth) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (Auth.isLogin()) {
        deferred.resolve();
    } else {
        deferred.reject();
        $location.url('/login');
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};


angular.module('YourModule')
.factory('Auth', function() {
var isLogin = function() {
console.log(localStorage.isLogged)
return localStorage.isLogged === "true";
}
return {isLogin: isLogin}
})

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController',
        resolve: {loggedIn: onlyLoggedIn}
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

Comment: OK, I will try this. @Arif

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle things during routing. When the user is not logged-in and the page requested requires otherwise, you should redirect to a different page such as 'Unauthorized.html' or something similar.

I'm using `$routeProvider` for routing. I haven't tried using angular ui-router so forgive me if this doesn't suit your needs.

I added a property `loginRequired` on my routing as well as `requiredRoles` to identify if the current user has access to a specific page.

Using `$routeChangeStart` I am checking if the page conditions is satisfied such as if the current user is logged-in and has authority to access the page. Failure to meet the conditions, I navigate to a different page.

Code extracted from my old project:

```
.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", "$httpProvider", "KeepaliveProvider", "IdleProvider",
            function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider, KeepaliveProvider, IdleProvider) {

            var templateLocation = "/Templates";

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: true,
                rewriteLinks: true
            }).hashPrefix("#");

            $routeProvider
                .when("/", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Home.html", //"/Product-List.html", // 
                    controller: "HomeController", //"ProductController", // 
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/Report", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Report.html",
                    controller: "ReportController",
                    loginRequired: true,
                    requiredRoles: ["Admin"]
                })
                .when("/About", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/About.html",
                    controller: "AboutController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/Contact", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Contact.html",
                    controller: "ContactController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/Register", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Register.html",
                    controller: "RegisterController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/Login", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Login.html",
                    controller: "LoginController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/User-List", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/User-List.html",
                    controller: "UserController",
                    loginRequired: true,
                    requiredRoles: ["Admin", "Secretary"]
                })
                .when("/User-Profile/:userId", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/User-Profile.html",
                    controller: "UserController",
                    loginRequired: true,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/TermsAndCondition", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Terms-And-Condition.html",
                    controller: "SupportController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/EmailConfirmed", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/EmailConfirmed.html",
                    controller: "SupportController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/ResetPassword", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/ResetPassword.html",
                    controller: "SupportController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/ForgotPassword", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/ForgotPassword.html",
                    controller: "SupportController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/Unauthorized", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Unauthorized.html",
                    controller: "UnauthorizedController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .when("/ErrorHandler", {
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/ErrorHandler.html",
                    controller: "ErrorController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                })
                .otherwise({
                    templateUrl: templateLocation + "/Error404.html",
                    controller: "ErrorController",
                    loginRequired: false,
                    requiredRoles: []
                });

        }])             
 .run(["$q", "$rootScope", "$location", "AccountService", "Idle", function ($q, $rootScope, $location, AccountService, Idle) {

            Idle.watch();
            var templateLocation = "/Templates";
            var postLogInRoute;

            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, nextRoute, currentRoute) {
                if (AccountService.isLoggedIn() &&
                    (nextRoute.templateUrl == templateLocation + "/Register.html" ||
                    nextRoute.templateUrl == templateLocation + "/Login.html")) {
                    $location.path("/Unauthorized").replace();
                    postLogInRoute = $location.path();
                }
                else if (nextRoute.loginRequired && !AccountService.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $location.path("/Login").replace();
                    postLogInRoute = $location.path();
                }
                else if (nextRoute.templateUrl.length != templateLocation + "/Unauthorized.html" && !AccountService.isUserAuthorized(nextRoute.requiredRoles)) {
                    $location.path("/Unauthorized").replace();
                    postLogInRoute = $location.path();
                }
                //else if (postLogInRoute && AccountService.isLoggedIn()) {
                //    $location.path(postLogInRoute).replace();
                //    postLogInRoute = null;
                //}
                else {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            });

        }])
```